# Why does scrapy provide unable to load error?

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

So i am working on a small crawler using scrapy and python on this website https://www.theverge.com/reviews. From there i am trying to extract the reviews based on the rules i have set which should match links that match this criteria:

> example: https://www.theverge.com/22274747/tern-hsd-p9-ebike-review-electric-cargo-bike-price-specs

Extracting the url from the review page, title of the page, name of who made the review and the link to their profile. However i assume there is something either wrong with my code or something wrong with the way i have my files sorted. Because this error when i try to run it:

> runspider: error: Unable to load 'spiders/vergespider.py': No module named 'oblig3.oblig3'

My folders look like this.

[image: My folders look like this]

So my intended results should look something like this. Visiting up to 20 pages, which i don't quite understand how to fix through the scrapy settings, but that is another problem.

```
authorlink,authorname,title,url
"https://www.theverge.com/authors/cameron-faulkner,https://www.twitter.com/camfaulkner",Cameron 
Faulkner,"Gigabyte’s Aorus 15G is great at gaming, but not much
else",https://www.theverge.com/22299226/gigabyte-aorus-15g-review-gaming-laptop-price-specs-features
```

So my question is what could be causing the error i am getting why am i not getting any csv output from this code. I am fairly new at python and scrapy oo any tips or improvement to the code are appreciated. I would like to keep the "solutions" through scrapy and python as those are the things i am trying to learn atm.

Edit:
This is what i use to run the code with `scrapy runspider spiders/vergespider.py -o vergetest.csv -t csv`. And this is what i have coded so far.

```
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from oblig3.items import VergeReview


class VergeSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'verge'

    allowed_domains = ['theverge.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.theverge.com/reviews']

    rules = [
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'^(https://www.theverge.com/)(/d+)/([%5E/]+$)%27'),
             callback='parse_items', follow=True),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'.*'),
             callback='parse_items', cb_kwargs={'is_verge': False})
    ]

    def parse(self, response, is_verge):
        if is_verge:
            verge = VergeReview()
            verge['url'] = response.url
            verge['title'] = response.xpath("//h1/text()").extract_first()
            verge['authorname'] = response.xpath("//span[@class='c-byline__author-name']/text()").extract()
            verge['authorlink'] = response.xpath("//*/span[@class = 'c-byline__item'][1]/a/@href").extract()
            yield verge
        else:
            # Do something else
            pass
```

My items file

```
import scrapy


class VergeReview(scrapy.Item):
    url = scrapy.Field()
    title = scrapy.Field()
    authorname = scrapy.Field()
    authorlink = scrapy.Field()
```

And my settings file is unchanged though i should implement CLOSESPIDER_PAGECOUNT = 20 but idk how.

Comment: What is the code that you have?

Answer (score 0):

The error you have is:

```
runspider: error ..... No module named 'oblig3.oblig3'
```

What I can see from your screenprint is that oblig3 is the name of your project.

This is a common error when you try to run your spider using:

```
scrapy runspider spider_file.py
```

If you are running your spider this way, you need to change the way you are running the spider:
First, make sure that you are in the directory where scrapy.cfg is located
then run

```
scrapy list
```

This should give you a list of all the spiders it found.

After that, you should use this command to run your spider.

```
scrapy crawl <spidername>
```

If this does not solve your problem, you need to share the code and share the details about how you are running your spider.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i just posted the code and the command!

Comment: Use scrapy Crawl verge to run your spider. If you use scrapy runspider command, it will ignore other files in the project. Also, if my answer is helpful, please mark it as Accepted

Comment: That does work but i can't write anything to a csv if i run the spider that way.

Comment: How are you writing to CSV?
Use FEEDS in setting.py
https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#std-setting-FEEDS

Comment: Using the command scrapy crawl <spider name> -o file.csv -t csv

Comment: Use FEEDS in settings